# Reading a file and printing a specific answer

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I read a text file called `CJ.txt` containing `2` columns`(z and mub)` and `31` rows. ((I just write the important part of my program)).
The question is how to define or call a "r" to reach an appropriate answer for example: I would like to print `r[25]`. It need `r[25]=mub[25]*z[25]`
Another `r[i]`, `i` from `0` to `31` can be obtained similar to above.

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import odeint
min=l=m=n=b=t=chi=r=None
f=0
z,mub=np.genfromtxt('CJ.txt',unpack=True) # opening the text file

for i in range(len(z)): # This means from 0 to 31
   r[i]=mub[i]*z[i]  # need a function similar to this

   print(r[5],r[31],r[2],r[12]) #and other r
```

or creating an array

```
  x=[[r[1],r[5],r[7]],
    [r[31],r[26],r[20]],
    [r[21],r[12],r[14]]]
```

I don't know that this question is easy or hard, but it is very important to me.
I appreciate you time and your attention.

Comment: I dont really get what you want to achieve, do you just want a function that multiplies the entries in the same row of both columns?

Comment: I want to obtain r. the equation of r can be everything, doesn't matter, i want to call r[1] or r[5] or r[15] or... and see the value of that. As i wrote for array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you looking for?

```
z,mub=np.genfromtxt('CJ.txt',unpack=True) # opening the text file
r = []
for i in range(len(z)): # This means from 0 to 31
    r.append(mub[i]*z[i])  # need a function similar to this

print(r[5],r[31],r[2],r[12]) #and other r
```

Comment: thank you. my problem is not the multiplication of two component. I want a simple way to call r from 1 to 31 and see the answer and use it anywhere else. for example i want to have r[27].

Comment: @Ehsan sorry, don't really understand what you mean. In this code snippet you basically create list of r values and then you can get any value of r you need. Do you mean, you don't want to create an array and want to calculate a single answer directly reading specific line of a file?

Comment: Could you give me a way to open file similar to my code and call components as I wanted in my code? Thank you my friend

Comment: yes in your code exactly pinpointed the answer i want, r[5] or other else. but please give me a code similar to my written code not other ways. because i have to change 400 lines code!

Comment: Ah man, I will check it in couple mins. God bless you. it Really helps me. Thank you so much

Comment: Dear friend, I have another question of my full program. where can i ask you? I thanks your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158629/discussion-between-ehsan-and-asakryukin).